# TypeError: Can Only Concatenate str (Not 'int') to str - Issue with Type Conversion in Python code

Tags: python-3.x

I'm practicing programming, and have the following code:

```
inp = int(input()) #3
inp1 = input().split() #1 2 3
list = []
for i in range(0, inp+1):
    for j in range(i-1, inp+1):
        if not not inp1[i:j]:
            if inp1[i:j] not in list:
                list.append(inp1[i:j])
for i in list:
    a = []
    print(type(i))
    for j in range(0, len(i)):
        a.append(int(i[j]))
    if sorted(i) == list(range(min(i), max(i)+1)):
        print(a)
```

Now, when i run the above, Python gave this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Wheatley/Documents/tinhoctre2.py", line 14, in <module>
    if sorted(i) == list(range(min(i), max(i)+1)):
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I tried to do all sorts of thing to convert the types but failed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using this ?

Comment: Welcome @Wheatley! What things did you try and failed?

Comment: I fixed your code but it returns another error, add `inp1 = [int(p) for p in inp1]` between line 2 and 3.

Comment: On line 15, I was trying to check if "i" is a consecutive list of integers after getting sorted.

Comment: Please do not use `list` as a variable `name`